# como puedo cambiar las varibles root de css con js para hacer un efecto de claro y oscuro

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trato de que todo lo de root se pueda cambiar con js mediante un boton.
Porque lo que hacer un efecto de claro y oscuro, con esa función realiza el cambio poro no se como hacer que lo revierta.

```
    <script>    
function cambioColor() {
       
    document.querySelector(&quot;html&quot;).style.setProperty(&#39;--coloruno&#39;, &quot;#131313&quot;);
    document.querySelector(&quot;html&quot;).style.setProperty(&#39;--colorFondo&#39;, &quot;#090909&quot;);
    document.querySelector(&quot;html&quot;).style.setProperty(&#39;--headingColor&#39;, &quot;#ffffff&quot;);
    document.querySelector(&quot;html&quot;).style.setProperty(&#39;--linkColor&#39;, &quot;#ffffff&quot;);
    document.querySelector(&quot;html&quot;).style.setProperty(&#39;--footerColor&#39;, &quot;#131313&quot;);
    document.querySelector(&quot;html&quot;).style.setProperty(&#39;--colordos&#39;, &quot;#090909&quot;);
   
}
</script>

:root{
    --coloruno: $colorP; 
    --colordos: $colorBuscador; 
    --colorFondo: $colorFondo;
    --headingColor: $headingColor; 
    --linkColor: $linkColor;
    --footerColor: $footerColor;
}

  <div class='toggle'>

  <input onclick='cambioColor()' id='checktoggle' type='checkbox'/>
  <label for='checktoggle'/>
  
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué error da?

Comment: No puedes modificar reglas de CSS porque no forman parte del DOM, en todo caso, tienes que cargar un CSS adicional para sobrescribir las reglas deseadas.

Comment: y como hago eso ??

Comment: Se pude cambiar todo el css:`<style id="s">p{color:blue;}/*Le damos un id uníco para identificarlo*//*Si "p" es azul nó funcionó.*/

</style>
<p id="p">Esto es ahora rojo.
</p>
<script>
var a=document.getElementById("s");/*retornamos el elemento style*/
a.innerHTML="p{color:red;}";/*Cambiamos todo el contenido del css*/

</script>`  . @Triby ¿Esto es lo qué te refieres con sobre escribir el css?

Comment: No, me refiero a que debes cargar otra hoja de estilos que contenga las mismas reglas con diferentes colores.

Comment: @Triby insteresante: `var a=document.createElement("style"); a.src="...";document.head.appendChild(a);`

Comment: Así es. Dame unos minutos para preparar una respuesta

Answer (score 2):

No se pueden modificar reglas de CSS porque no forman parte del DOM. La forma más usada es tener diferentes hojas de estilo y cargarlas para modificar la apariencia. Se necesita una pequeña función en Javascript para cargar y activar o desactivar un estilo:

```
function loadCss(file, disable = false) {
    // Evitar cargar más de una vez
    let link = document.querySelector(`link[href="${file}"]`);

    if(!link) {
        // Todavía no se ha cargado el archivo, crear elemento y asignar propiedades
        link = document.createElement('link');
        link.href = file;
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.media = "screen,print";
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    }
    // Activar o desactivar
    link.disabled = disable;
}
```

Ahora, ya debes tener el tema por defecto cargado y con reglas como:

```
:root {
    --texto:#777;
    --fondo:#fff;
}
body {
    color:var(--texto);
    background:var(--fondo);
}
```

Debes tener otro archivo para modo oscuro, digamos `dark-mode.css`, donde solo tienes reglas para "sobrescribir" las variables, no necesitas modificar nada más:

```
:root {
    --texto:#ccc;
    --fondo:#333;
}
```

Finalmente, el checkbox y Javascript para cambiar entre modos:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-mode">
    Modo oscuro
</label>

<script>
// Debes cargar primero el script que tiene la función loadCss()

// Obtener checkbox
let checkMode = document.querySelector('#toggle-mode');
// Escuchar cambios
checkMode.addEventListener('change', () => {
    // Cargar y activar o desactivar de acuerdo al estado del checkbox
    // Enviar falso cuando el checkbox está marcado para activar
    // O verdadero para desactivar
    loadCss('ruta/dark-mode.css', !checkMode.checked);
});
</script>
```

Solo recuerda que las hojas de estilos se cargan mediante una etiqueta `<link ...>`, mientras que `<style>` es para agregar estilos directamente en HTML y no es tan fácil manipularlos.

Answer (score 1):

En los tags de la pregunta se encuentra CSS, por lo que asumo puedes usar CSS, el código anterior se simplificaría bastante aplicando un Class que determine el diseño para cada estado:

```js
function cambioColor(checkbox){
    let button = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
  
  //console.log(button.innerHTML);
  //console.log(button.classList.toggle);
  button.classList.toggle("light", checkbox.checked)

}
```

```css
.button{
  font:400 13px/13px sans-serif;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:8px 12px;
  color:#555;
  background-color:#FFF;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius:3px;
  cursor:default;
}

.button.light{
  background-color:#5371B5;
  color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class='toggle'>

  <div>
    <b class='button'>Botón demo</b>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label><input onclick='cambioColor(this)' type='checkbox'/> Cambiar color</label>
  </div>
 
</div>
```