# Como seleccionar una clase css con jquery de una hoja de estilo externa

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

estoy tratando de seleccionar un boton cada vez que lo pulso cambia a un estilo diferente de mi css, el problema es que este código está hecho para el codigo css en linea, si yo quiero cogerlo por ejemplo de la carpeta

> css/stilos.css

y hacer que jquery encuentre la clase de alli como debería hacerlo? esto se puede?

```
const switchButton = $("button#switch");
 
$('button').click(switchButton, function(e) {

    document.body.classList.toggle('dark'); //toggle the HTML body the class 'dark'
    switchButton.classList.toggle('active');//toggle the HTML button with the id='switch' with the class 'active'
});
```

adjunto tambien el codigo html

```
<button class="darkModeSwitch" id="switch">
      <span><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></span>   
      <span><i class="fas fa-sun"></i></span>
```

Me gustaría saber si estas lineas:

```
document.body.classList.toggle('dark'); //toggle the HTML body the class 'dark'

switchButton.classList.toggle('active');//toggle the HTML button with the id='switch' with the class 'active'
```

hay alguna forma de llamarlas de otro modo que yo desconozco para acceder a este fichero css externo y que consiga estas clases.

Comment: Vincula ese archivo `css` en tu `html`

Comment: No es con _jQuery_, pero tal vez [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/435025/54039) pueda servirte; carga una hoja de estilos adicional al activar el modo oscuro.

Comment: no es exactamente lo que busco, pero seguramente me sirva mas adelante esta respuesta, la guardaré. Habría algun modo de colocar las clases de una hoja externa de css ? por jquery ? o tendre que ir a colocarlo en linea para que si lo detecte bien?

Comment: @JohnDoe la ruta del css seria algo asi css/stilos.css  las clases que coge son dark y active que estan definidas en este css, no hace falta añadirlas creo yo ya que el efecto que hacen como tal no es el motivo de la pregunta sino, el jquery y como puede acceder a estas clases.Pero si es totalmente necesario las adjunto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes estilizar la pagina entera en dos colores o diferentes estilos fácilmente mediante css y en js modificarle un atributo o clase a la etiqueta `<body>` y cambiara los estilos.

Ejemplo

css:

```
body{
  background: #fff; //---------> estilos de body generales
}
body.dark-mode{
  background: #000; //---------> estilos de body generales en dark-mode
  color: #fff;
}
//---------------
//BOTON
body button.darkModeSwitch{
  //.... Codigo del boton
}
body.dark-mode button.darkModeSwitch{
  //.... Codigo del boton en dark-mode
}
//---------------
//LUNA Y SOL
body button.darkModeSwitch .moon{
  display: none; //--------> esconder la luna
}
body.dark-mode button.darkModeSwitch .sun{
  display: none; //---------> esconde el sol en dark-mode
}
```

js:

```
const switchButton = $("button#switch");
 
$('button').click(switchButton, function(e) {

    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode'); //toggle dark-mode
});
```

html:

```
<button class="darkModeSwitch" id="switch">
      <span><i class="fas fa-moon moon"></i></span>   
      <span><i class="fas fa-sun sun"></i></span>
</button>
```

Si vas a hacer modificaciones a gran escala de la web cuando se vea en dark-web puedes usar variables de css [Doc de W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp)

Este metodo es util para no ir uno a uno dandole clases a los elementos en js

Comment: el css lo puedo crear en una hoja externa y lo cogera?? o todo esto es css en linea?Necesito crearlo en una hoja externa

Comment: El css puede ser hoja externa, lo unico que afecta es la class="dark-mode", porque los estilos de body.dark-mode se sobreescribira al css normal. Solo en js le añades la clase o lo borras y css hara su efecto

Comment: no termino de entenderte entonces si el código que implementas aqui tu de css esta en la hoja externa de ModoOscuro.css (por ejemplo), el js en otra hoja externa y el html por otro ladod eberia funcionar bien ?

Comment: si porque al final en html las incluyes